# Using Key Value Observing to detect when an object gets deallocated

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

How can I find out when an object is being released? I am listening for kvo changes, but the object get's deallocated before the retain count goes to 0, and I get the following warning:

**An instance 0x16562be0 of class MyViewController was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:**

Basically what I'm trying to do is to detect when the model is dismissed. **I can't use a Delegate**, because the viewControllers being presented are dynamic, and my mainViewController has no knowledge about them other than the fact that they are subclasses of UIViewController.

```
[anotherViewController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"retainCount" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    // Here check for the changes and see of the new value is 0 or not
}
```

I also tried listening for the superView of the viewController being changed to nil

```
[anotherViewController.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"superView" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior context:nil];
```

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: To be more specific about your case, ignoring all the other good reasons why you should *never* use retainCount, KVO only works on properties for which a class is KVO-compliant. I've never had a reason to care before, but I'm willing to bet that retainCount is not KVO-compliant.

You'll need to take an entirely different approach to reacting to your view controllers being dismissed (or is it deallocated? They're not the same thing...).

Comment: @AndrewMadsen: Classes literally *can't* be KVO-compliant for `retainCount` in the sense that he is looking for here, because it can never be 0 for anything that isn't nil.

Comment: Note that the documentation for the `-retainCount` method says this: **Do not use this method.**

Comment: @Chuck, yes of course you're right.

Comment: So any other way to detect a ViewController being dismissed without using delegate?

Comment: @aryaxt: You should ask a separate question about that.

Comment: If the *only* thing that the main view controller knows is that the other view controllers are instances of `UIViewController`, why does it need to use KVO or otherwise know when they've been dismissed? Conversely, if the main view controller needs to know that another view controller has been dismissed, then it needs to know more than *just* that the the view controller is a view controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only do Key-Value Observing on keys for which the object supports it. What you want to do here is simply not possible — an object's observers are all supposed to be gone by the time it gets to `dealloc`. You will need to structure your application such that either this object is kept around as long as it is needed or it actively tells interested parties before it goes away.

And looking at an object's `retainCount` is just never a good idea. As far as it is useful, it is only useful for debugging — and even then there are much better and more reliable tools. The result of `retainCount` is simply misleading, and it does not work the way most people expect. Watching for it to be 0 is an exercise in futility, because no object can exist with a retain count of 0 — when an object with a retain count of 1 is released, it gets deallocated, and then you are not allowed to message it anymore. (In fact, the framework literally has no way of representing a 0 retain count because it's an unreachable state.)

Answer (score 5):

### UPDATE

As of late 2017 (iOS 11, macOS 10.13), when an object is deallocated, it automatically unregisters any remaining observers. From the [Foundation release notes for that year](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html):

> #### Relaxed Key-Value Observing Unregistration Requirements
>
> Prior to 10.13, KVO would throw an exception if any observers were
> still registered after an autonotifying object's -dealloc finished
> running. Additionally, if all observers were removed, but some were
> removed from another thread during dealloc, the exception would
> incorrectly still be thrown. This requirement has been relaxed in
> 10.13, subject to two conditions:
>
> - The object must be using KVO autonotifying, rather than manually
>   calling -will and -didChangeValueForKey: (i.e. it should not return NO
>   from +automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:)
> - The object must not
>   override the (private) accessors for internal KVO state
>
> If all of these are true, any remaining observers after -dealloc
> returns will be cleaned up by KVO; this is also somewhat more
> efficient than repeatedly calling -removeObserver methods.

And as of late 2020 (iOS 14, macOS 10.16), [KVO is even more careful](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14-beta-release-notes/#Key-Value-Observing) when an object still has observers during deallocation:

> #### Key-Value Observing
>
> #### New Features in iOS & iPadOS 14 beta 5
>
> - Key-Value Observation removal facilities now employ deterministic
>   bookkeeping methods. Cases that would have produced hard-to-diagnose
>   crashes, especially those where KVO signals problems accessing
>   deallocated observer pointers or observers associated with incorrect
>   objects, now produce an exception pinpointing which observed object
>   needs a missed `removeObserver(_:)` call, and by which observers. This
>   exception was previously thrown as ‘best effort’ when KVO could detect
>   the problem; the new deterministic bookkeeping allows it to be thrown
>   for all cases where `removeObserver(_:)` is needed.
>
>   The improved determinism also allows improved Swift API handling.
>   Instances of `NSKeyValueObservation`, produced by the Swift
>   `NSObject.observe(_:changeHandler:)` method, take advantage of
>   integration with this bookkeeping so they now invalidate automatically
>   when the observed object is released, regardless of how the object
>   implements its KVO behavior. This applies to all usage of this API in
>   macOS 11 Big Sur beta, including on processes built with previous
>   versions of the SDK, and eliminates certain classes of crashes that
>   sometimes required using the legacy API instead. (65051563)

### ORIGINAL

There are a few problems here.

One problem is that you asked the wrong question.  You meant to ask “How do I deregister my observer at the right time, before the target is deallocated?”  Instead, you mentioned `retainCount`, which tends to provoke people into berating you about using `retainCount` instead of helping you do what you're trying to do, which is deregister your observer at the right time.

Another problem is that your view controller doesn't own its model (meaning it doesn't have a strong reference to the model).  Usually you want your view controller to own its model, to prevent exactly this sort of problem.  While your view controller exists, it needs a model to operate on, so it should own the model.  When the view controller is being deallocated, it should stop observing its model and release it.  (If you're using ARC, it will release the model automatically at the end of `dealloc`).  You might also choose to deregister in your `viewWillDisappear:` method, if your view controller goes on and off of the screen repeatedly.

Note that an object can be owned by multiple other objects simultaneously.  If you have several view controllers operating on the same model, they should all own the model, meaning that they should all have strong references to the model.

A third problem is that you're (probably) using KVO directly.  The built-in KVO API is not very pleasant to use.  Take a look at [`MAKVONotificationCenter`](https://github.com/mikeash/MAKVONotificationCenter).  This KVO wrapper automatically unregisters an observer when the observer or the target is deallocated.

Comment: `MAKVONotificationCenter` is convenient, but tying de-registration of observers as an automatic behavior of `dealloc` can lead to really weird and difficult to fix bugs.  The object graph is likely inconsistent during the deallocation of any given object.  Change observation should be removed *before* the object graph is reaped.

Comment: I would be curious to see an example of such a bug.

Comment: Comes up often in Xcode and other complex applications;  the real killer is order dependencies in object graph teardown, but KVOs being fired during object graph teardown have come up, too.   By moving to a very disciplined "invalidate then destroy" model, the # of bugs was greatly reduced.  The trigger is typically a setter being called that fires an observer than then tries to muck with the now disconnected object graph.

Answer (score 2):

if you are interested in getting notified when an object gets deallocated you could send a notification in dealloc, but don't reference the object getting dealloc'ed.

for instance

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myclass_dealloced" \
                                      object:[NSValue valueWithPointer:self]];
```

but you wouldn't ever want to dereference that pointer...

**use this only for debugging and testing.**

Comment: I thought about it, but I don't like this solution. I want it to be automated.

Comment: in a testing framework I made I swizzled away alloc / copy / dealloc and made it happen automatically... I probably can't post that code, but I made use of JRSwizzle (i think that is what it is called) to do the swizzling pretty painlessly then I sent distributed notifications and had another process with a UI watching for the events.

Comment: I really like method swizzling except, I never found a way to intercept the method, and then call the original. Any idea whether that's possible or not?

Comment: absolutely you swizzle the original method to a method called originalDealloc then call that in your dealloc... or since deallocs are simple enough you can usually re-impliment it.

Comment: Very cool, I'm trying to write an NSObject Category to do this. Still not working, but I think I'm close. https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMethodInterceptor

Comment: @aryaxt looking good, I had each class register in the +initialize method, but I suspect you can do it anywhere you like...

Comment: not ideal because the notification gets triggered in the thread it was sent meaning the receiver side might assume there is some valid thread while the object nore the thread just dont exist, plus it is not KVO.

Comment: @OlSen certainly you couldn't expect anything about the object that was deallocated to exist... the thread may or may not.

Comment: in that case you dont need to send the pointer as reference anyway. As Notification means also anywhere in code a deallocation can be imposed while actually not happening. With KVO that is bound to the observed object this never happens.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to automatically de-register observers during `dealloc` is **too late**.

When `dealloc` is called, the state of the object graph is undefined.  Specifically, order of deallocation is typically not guaranteed and may often change in light of asynchronous processes and/or `autorelease`.

While the graph the deallocating object strongly references should be coherent, that'll quickly change as the object is deallocated.

The same holds true for the observer of the object being deallocated;  as deallocation of an object graph happens, the observed objects state may likely change.   As it changes, it may cause observers to fire while the object graph is in the inconsistent, being deallocateed, state.

You really need to concretely separate deallocation from observation logic.

That is, when your controller is dismissed from screen, it should actively dismiss the model layer, including tearing down any observers (or notifying any observers that the model layer is about to go away).

Answer (score 0):

Your observers need to de-register their notifications at the same time they let go of the object.

For example, if your objects are registering notifications on one of their properties, de-register all the notifications before the property is changed or set to nil.

There never should be "hanging" notification registrations to objects that have been simply lost track of. How can you deregister your notifications if you lose track of the object?

Answer (score 0):

just do what KVO says. Observe, act accordingly and signal the Key manually when you need to. That way you can of course know when an object gets deallocated.
When you removeObserver from the Object and it is already deallocated then the method call is acting on nil which does no harm or your observing object holds still a reference and in such case you can still act accordingly.

With ARC this is not a problem and one of the great benefits.

Test it yourself..

```objectivec
// public header.
@interface ObjectToBeObserved : NSObject
@end

// declare in private header
// because you dont want to allow triggering from outside
@interface ObjectToBeObserved : NSObject
// use some artificial property to make it easy signalling manually.
@property (nonatomic) BOOL willDealloc;
@end

@implementation ObjectToBeObserved 
-(void)dealloc {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"willDealloc"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"willDealloc"];
}
@end
```

In your Observer side you just do classic KVO design pattern..

```objectivec
void* objectDeallocatedContext = & objectDeallocatedContext;
@implementation ObservingObject {
    // easy to see you could even make a protocol out of the design pattern
    // that way you could guarantee your delegate has such property to observe
    __weak ObjectToBeObserved *delegate;
}
-(instancetype)initWithObservableDelegate:(ObjectToBeObserved*)observable {
    if (!(self=[super init])) return nil;
    delegate = observable;
    // see i use observe old value here..
    if (delegate!=nil)
        [delegate addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"willDealloc" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:objectDeallocatedContext];
    return self;
}
-(void)dealloc {
    if (delegate!=nil)
        [delegate removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"willDealloc" context: objectDeallocatedContext];
}
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context==objectDeallocatedContext) {
        NSLog(@"the observed object deallocated");
        // in theory you hold still a weak reference here 
        // which should be nil after this KVO signal arrived.
        // the object in the signal therefore might not be valid anymore,
        // which is what you want when observing deallocation.
    }
}
@end
```

KVO is a signal pattern, not a way to know if a signalling object is still valid. But when the object is gone it will not signal anything, those when you can receive the signal you are just fine. Because i choose to watch the `NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld` value with a `void* context`, it gets even signaled before the objects artificial "willDealloc" property is set (well, not even set). The KVO can arrive without a valid object but has still a context to compare to. You just need the ping